# Is this JavaScript mailto redirect vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript, dom

I am working on a XSS attack and I do not think it's vulnerable after numerous hours of trying. However, a second opinion would be great.

```
<script language='javascript'>
  var redirecturl = 'mailto:xsss@m0chan.com?mkt_tok=mailtokenhere%3D%3D';
  function redirect() {
    var anchor = window.location.hash;
    window.self.location = redirecturl + anchor;
  }
</script>
```

My initial attraction to this was the fact that it's passing the value of `anchor` into `window.self.location = redirecturl + anchor;`. However I think that using `mailto` here makes XSS impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more injection than XSS, but [Mailto links have a few features](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/) that you can abuse. For example, instead of the email program popping up with just the TO filled out, you can pre-fill the CC, BCC, Subject, and Body. This is done by editing the query string, e.g. `?subject=xyz&cc=other@example.com`.

My first thought was that `window.location.hash` would prevent adding anything to the query string, due to the `#`. However, I tested it on Chrome, and it seems to be possible.

So using this, somebody malicious could add sneak a few things into the email and hope that it goes unnoticed. For example, the malicious actor could send a blind carbon copy to an account they control:

```
https://example.com/contact#&bcc=evilminion@example.com

mailto:xss@example.com?mkt_tok=mailtokenhere%3D%3D#&bcc=evilminion@example.com
```

Or they could insert advertisements:

```
https://example.com/contact#&body=%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0ABuy%20your%20foobar%20cheap%20at%20example.com%2Ffoobar

mailto:xss@example.com?mkt_tok=mailtokenhere%3D%3D#&body=%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0ABuy%20your%20foobar%20cheap%20at%20example.com%2Ffoobar
```

This will still depend on the email client to include these other headers. [RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068) discourages clients from adding anything beyond "a limited set" of headers that are deemed to be safe, such as subject, keywords, and body.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the prompt descriptive response :)